# Initialze class (scrapy Item) with empty strings

Tags: python, scrapy

I am inserting a scrapy Item class that I have defined in `items.py` into a mongodb, but I need it to insert all fields of the class so it will add those fields in the db as empty. `Name` and `Price` under the listing class will always be inserted as empty, but I want to keep `pipelines.py` clean so I can switch in another item easily. Currently if I don't set each part of the class to an empty string it will not add that when inserting into the db.

Do I need to initialize each member as an empty dict? something like `Title = scrapy.Field({})`

items.py

```
class Listing(scrapy.Item):
    Title = scrapy.Field()
    Address = scrapy.Field()
    Price = scrapy.Field()
    Name = scrapy.Field()
```

pipelines.py

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):

    # Price and Name will always be empty
    item['Price'] = ''
    item['Name'] = ''
    self.collection.insert_one(dict(item))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use scrapy's [ItemLoader](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html):

```
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
class Listing(Item):
    title = Field()
    address = Field()
    price = Field()
    name = Field()

class MyLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_item_class = Listing
```

and then:

```
loader = MyLoader(response=response)
loader.add_xpath('title', '//some/xpath/that/finds/nothing')
loader.load_item()
# {'title': ['']}
```